# Como puedo crear una consulta que reste cierto porcentaje?

Tags: sql

tengo una tabla con  cierta cantidad de precio según cada articulo, me gustaria saber como puedo  restarle al  precio un porcentaje, por ejemplo 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comienza con la sentencia `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE Tabla
SET precio = precio * 0.7
WHERE -- las filas que quieras actualizar
```

Comment: Tienes razón, me apuré en contestar, lo que necesita es un query.

Comment: SI QUISIERA AFECTAR A TODAS LAS FILAS DE LA TABLA?

Comment: Si lo hace al mostrar los datos pero lo que necesito es que los modifique

Comment: Revertí a mi respuesta original con UPDATE, esta sí modifica los datos en la tabla. Si necesitas modificar toda la tabla simplemente omite la parte del WHERE.

Comment: Gracias!! funcionó muy bien.

Comment: @shadow El usuario lo mencionó en un comentario y es claramente parte de su intención.  Me parece completamente apropiado agregarlo.

Comment: @shadow Comparto tu punto de vista de ayudar a los usuarios a aprender.  La edición de su pregunta le llegará como notificación, me pareció un paso extra por esta vez.  Además es un usuario nuevo, tratemos de no regañarlos mucho. :)

Comment: no, para nada de hecho si observas por eso por que es nuevo le quite el voto negativo igual que a ti; aprendamos juntos; lo ultimo que dije solo es una observación